# PHP Require In different folders

Tags: php, require

Okay so on my website I have a scripts folder which includes a php file which connects to mysql server so If I move a database then It will change it on all the files which are connect to the database.

I also have another folder called templates. In that folder there is a top for the header and the footer. In the header template I wrote:

```
require("../scripts/connect.php");
```

And I have another folder called, category. And that folder includes the header and the header includes connect. But then it displays and error that there is no such files.

Please help. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by moving your database?

Comment: Elaborate more. What doesn't find what?

Comment: Keep in mind that script location and working directory are not one and the same. [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/getcwd)

Comment: php use the running script path when doing include or require, not the  included script path, check my answer, I hope it will give you a solution for your problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A good practice is to include a main config in all running php files, usually called config.php :)

in this config file create a constant called SITE_ROOT or something similar that point to the exact folder like this
`define("SITE_ROOT", "/var/www/mysite");`

Then on any include, include_once, require, require_once use it like this:

```
require(SITE_ROOT."/scripts/connect.php");
```

This should solve any relative path drama

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use relative paths with the include/require, but use a constant defining the ROOT_PATH of your website.

Example:
In all the files calling needing includes:

```
define(ROOT_PATH, '../');

include ROOT_PATH . '/scripts/connect.php';
```

And in /scripts/connect.php (and all the other files that will be included somewhere), all the includes should use ROOT_PATH (without defining it).