# What is exactly the batch script code and setup to successfully execute a php script

Tags: php, batch-file, path, cron

I have a php script that connects to a database and does inserts/updates, obviously, if I run the script using the browser, it executes successfully, moving it into production this won't happen.

I would like to ask how can I invoke the php.exe using a batch script that then runs the php script I have created to do the inserts/updates.

I have the ff: setup

I'm using xampp, with the ff:

webdirectory/cronjobs/cronjob.php -> does the inserts and updates
webdirectory/cronjobs/runscript.bat ->will run the cronjob.php

```
runscript.bat
@echo off
php.exe -f ../webdirectory/cronjobs/cronjob.php

cronjob.php

include_once('../db/dbcon.php');
$test = $db->run();
.... insert/update codes
```

Additionally, when I try to run the batch script directly using command line for Win7, using  ***drive:>/xampp/php/php.exe -f drive:>xampp/htdocs/webdirectory/cronjobs/cronjob.php***

I get the ff: error;

```
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../webdirectory/db/dbcon.php' for inclusion (include_path='.; E:\xampp\php\PEAR') in E:\xammp\htdocs\webdirectory\db\dbcon.php on line xx
```

I guess the relative file path is failing; Follow-up question tho, does that mean I have to edit my script file and set the path to absolute? Instead of using  **../webdirectory/db/dbcon.php** , I should use  **e:/xampp/htdocs/webdirectory/db/dbcon.php** ? Looks like a bad thing to me...

Can somebody please help?

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297096/php-require-in-different-folders/12297191#12297191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the directory to the location of the script to make all relative paths work when beeing executed from outside the script's directory

**cronjob.php**

```
chdir(__DIR__);
include_once('../db/dbcon.php');
```